# django class-based views for handling AJAX responses

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I was thinking about writing my own class-based views to consistently handle AJAX GET and AJAX POST (for posting form, which might return validation errors). Before I do so, I want to make sure I am not reinventing the wheel. Are there modules/apps out there already serving the said purpose?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8059160/

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I use the django-dajax and django-dajaxice packages available in the PyPI database  to handle AJAX related flow.

In my opinion, they created a very easy and eficient API to get the job done.
You can find out more about them following these links.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dajax

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dajaxice